# serialize (write) when using an intermediate ManyToMany model

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

**Can read/write** when using a **standard** ManyToMany model (no extra fields).
**Can read** when using an **intermediate** ManyToMany model (with extra fields).
**Cannot write** when using an **intermediate** ManyToMany model (with extra fields).

It fails due to DRF's lack of support for writable nested fields.

However, DRF does support writing the nested pk's of the standard ManyToMany model; the extra fields should add no ambiguity to the operation.

**Reading/writing** when using **standard** ManyToMany model works like this:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Group(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

serializers.py

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Person.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'group', 'persons')
```

**Reading** when using an **intermediate** ManyToMany model works like this:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Group(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership
    date = DateField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'group', 'person')

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    memberships = MembershipSerializer(source='membership_set', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'group', 'memberships')
```

What would be the solution to **write** when using an **intermediate** ManyToMany model?
Looking for something obvious that I've missed; I'd rather not implement custom create() and update() methods.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days ago. Perhaps the detailed answer will also help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633926/how-to-post-model-with-many-to-many-through-in-django-rest/49738300#49738300

Comment: It is indeed a similar question but, as mentioned, I was hoping to avoid the custom create/update methods.